# How can I serve HTML and JSON requests from the same route, using Symfony 2 and FOSRestBundle, using headers in addition to the _format?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, content-negotiation

I am attempting to serve content in both `html` and `json` formats (I also want to eventually allow for `xml` as well) using [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) and the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) (ver. 1.3). I have been successful at serving different content for routes using the `_format` parameter, e.g.:

- `/foo.json` will result in a JSON response,
- and `/foo` will result in an HTML response.

Is there any way to reconcile (on the same host!) the same content negotiation above using something other than `_format`, for example the `Content-Type` or `Accept` headers?

I've looked at the [Format Listener](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#format-listener) but I think that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to configure it.

---

Given the defined route:

```
<route id="foo" pattern="/foo.{_format}" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">FooBundle:Foo:get</default>
    <default key="_format">html</default>
</route>
```

... for the following action:

```
public function getAction(Request $request)
{
    $view = View::create()
        ->setData(array('greeting' => 'hello world'))
        ->setFormat($request->getRequestFormat('html'))
        ->setTemplate('FooBundle:Foo:get.html.twig');
    return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
}
```

... and the following FOSRestBundle configuration (snippet):

```
fos_rest:
  ...
  format_listener: true
```

I am required to specify the `_format` parameter in the request if I want negotiated content in a format other than the default (`html`), as above.

However, if I specify the following rules for the format listener:

```
fos_rest:
  format_listener:
    rules:
      - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: false }
      - { path: '^/', priorities: ['html', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
```

The browser request returns my responses as `Content-Type: application/json` but the actual content is the `text/html` content rather than the serialized JSON. If I explicitly specify the `Accept` header though on the request as `Accept: text/html` the response I receive is has a content type header of `Content-Type: text/html`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Content negotiation based on Content-type header you need BodyListener instead of FormatListener.
Read the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#body-listener).

Comment: Thanks, I read through the Body Listener (in fact that entire page) multiple times, but for whatever reason when I first read the section it never clicked that that was targeting the body's content type.